# Inserting an array into a relational table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have 3 tables:

- user_login
- doc_list
- user_cat_link_table

So I am creating a new user and apart of the form shows an array of the available categories which are pulled from the cat_list table.

I am struggling to along with the other form data update the user_cat_link_table.

The script to take the ID of the new user and take the ID of the category selected from the checkboxes array:

Here is my input form:

```
 <form action="actions/add_emp.php" method="post">

      <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" required="required"  /><br/>
      <input type="text" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password"/></label><br/>

        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="name" required="required" 
               placeholder="Firstname"/><br />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="email" required="required" 
               placeholder="Lastname"/><br/>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="city" required="required" 
               placeholder="Email Address"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="extension" id="extension" required="required" 
               placeholder="Extension Number"/><br/>
        <select name="title">
            <option  selected disabled>Please Select a Job Title...</option>

            <option disabled></option>
            <option disabled>Helpesk:</option>
            <option value="Technical Support Advisor">Technical Support Advisor</option>
            <option value="Deputy Team Leade">Deputy Team Leader</option>
            <option value="Team Leader">Team Leader</option>
            <option value="Incident Resolution Advisor">Incident Resolution Advisor
            </option>

            <option disabled></option>
            <option disabled>Call Centre:</option>
            <option value="Technical Support Advisor">Technical Support Advisor</option>
            <option value="">Deputy Team Leader</option>
            <option value="">Team Leader</option>

            <option disabled></option>
        </select>


<div id="checkboxlist" >
    <?php
        foreach($category as $cat){ 
    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $cat["cat_id"]; ?>" 
           name="cat_no[]" id="box1"> <?php echo $cat["cat_title"]; ?></a><br>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div> 
        <input type="submit" value="Add User" name="submit"/><br />
    </form>
```

I can see if I do a print_r() or var_dump() I am getting the results I expect:

```
Array ( [action] => id 
        [user] => test23wer3e4weret4essd 
        [pass] => test [firstname] => test 
        [lastname] => test 
        [email] => tes@test.com 
        [extension] => 1234 
        [cat_no] => Array ( [0] => 69 
                            [1] => 70 
                            [2] => 71 ) 
        [submit] => Add User )
```

Here is the form which acts as the script to insert the data into both the user_login table (which works) but its the part at the bottom trying to insert into the join table I am having trouble with:

```
<?
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
if(!ini_get('date.timezone'))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}

    if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    include_once'../../config.php';



    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dashboardr",$username,$password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

    if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
        $password=$_POST['pass'];
        $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user_login` WHERE `username`=?");
        $sql->execute(array($_POST['user']));

    if($sql->fetchColumn()!=0){

    die("User Exists");

    }else{
        function rand_string($length) {
        $str="";
        $chars = "subinsblogabcdefghijklmanopqrstuvwxyz
                            ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $size = strlen($chars);
        for($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++) {
        $str .= $chars[rand(0,$size-1)];
    }

    return $str; 
    }
        $p_salt = rand_string(20); 
        $site_salt="subinsblogsalt"; 
        $salted_hash = hash('sha256', $password.$site_salt.$p_salt);

        $sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_login` 
                           (`id`, `username`, `password`, `psalt`, 
                            `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `extension`) 
                             VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $sql->execute(
        array($_POST['user'], $salted_hash, $p_salt, $_POST["firstname"], 
              $_POST["lastname"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["extension"]));
        print_r($_POST);
        die();

        $docId = $dbh->lastInsertId();

$sql = "INSERT INTO `user_cat_link_table`(`UserID`, `Cat_ID`) VALUES";
$values = "";
$params = [];

foreach($_POST["cat_no"] as $cat)

{

    $values.= "(?, ?), ";
    $params[] = $cat; // correct here
    $params[] = $docId;
}
    $values = substr($values, 0, -2);
    $sql.= $values;
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);       

    if ($dbh->query($sql)) {

    }else{}

    $dbh = null;
    } //catch(PDOException $e)
 header ('Location: ../list_doc.php?success=1');

    }

    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What does it do instead of work as expected? Please post the final string value of `$sql` after all the params are concatenated. Does the final array `$params` look as expected when you `print_r($params)`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I tried to print_r($params) but it kills the script?

Comment: Just a quick note - you're trying to close an `input` tag with an `a` tag

Comment: Did you include a `;` on `print_r($params);` ?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yeah

Comment: You are using `substr($values, 0, -2)` which will remove two chars from the right of `$values`. Do you not only need to remove one trailing `,`? It looks like you may have removed the last `)` as well...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski sorry what should it look like?

Comment: Debug the final sql string with `echo $sql;` once `$values` has been built up with it. If I read all of this correctly, you would need `$values = substr($values, 0, -1);` to remove only the trailing `,`.

Comment: Where do you want me to echo $sql out from?

Comment: After `$sql.= $values;` Or use `die($sql);`

Comment: So that kills the script and returns nothing

Comment: If your script is terminating with no output (the "white screen of death"), that suggests you do not have error reporting turned up and displaying on screen. Always in development, at the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` If some syntax error is present, you'll see it.

Comment: That is the strange thing - I have exactly that query to return errors - if i then refresh the page it tells me the user exists though

Comment: You are stoping the script `print_r($_POST); die();` ...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I am getting this: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin\actions\add_emp_tester.php:69 Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin\actions\add_emp_tester.php(69): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin\actions\add_emp_tester.php on line 69` from using `$sql.= $values;1

Comment: @phpcoder Okay then, you next need to verify that the number of elements in the `$params` array exactly matches the number of `?` placeholders in the final `$sql` string.

Comment: Could you show me an example of this?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `echo $sql` I not get this result:   INSERT INTO `user_cat_link_table`(`UserID`, `Cat_ID`) VALUES
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin\actions\add_emp_tester.php:69 Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin\actions\add_emp_tester.php(69): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin\actions\add_emp_tester.php

Comment: now this is interesting: INSERT INTO `user_cat_link_table`(`UserID`, `Cat_ID`) VALUES
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dashboardr`.`user_cat_link_table`, CONSTRAINT `user_cat_link_table_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Cat_ID`) REFERENCES `cat_list` (`cat_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)' in...

Comment: The INSERT string terminating after `VALUES` indicates that at the time it ran, you had no values checked in `$_POST['cat_no']`. You would need to check `if (count($_POST['cat_no']) > 0)` before proceeding to `$query->prepare()`